# Changing Bootstrap container margin width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to override the `container` class CSS in my site which uses bootstrap. I have the style-page in the right spot but not sure which line to write to override .container's 'width' before changing to another width (when the window reduces). I want it to be wider by default.

```
<div class="container">

   // site content ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of variables which you can change in order to modify certain styles that Bootstrap provides.

Here is [the link to the container specific variables](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes)

Comment: I've seen that page before, which is why I asked the question. Not sure which of those is the one i'm looking for. Edited my question to be more specific

Comment: You would need to change all of them since each one depends on a certain browser window size.

Comment: oh, I was just hoping to make the content be wider, since it 'jumps' to different widths as the browser is scaled down to

Comment: It will always jump since the width change is usually a few hundred pixels. You could animate the size change using Javascript if you want. Not much point though as most people won't be changing the size of their window. They will load the site with one size and remain at that size.

Comment: Exactly, I was just hoping to alter those few hundred pixels

Comment: Then you can. The variables in the link I posted can be changed so you can make the container wider at certain screen sizes

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to re-write to many to achieve such a small thing